# Qt 4.7: Trigger context menu by gesture

Tags: qt4, webkit, gesture

I'm working on a finger friendly browser exercise with FlickCharm example and QtWebKit, here's [all the source code](https://github.com/penk/mkxpud/tree/master/skeleton/archive/qtouchweb) I have so far.

I want to trigger context by long press (tap-and-hold), currently I can get the QGestureEvent  and position in `eventFilter()` by

```
QGestureEvent *gestureEvent = dynamic_cast<QGestureEvent*>(event);
if (gestureEvent) {
    if (const QGesture *g = gestureEvent->gesture(Qt::TapAndHoldGesture)) {
        if (g->state() == Qt::GestureStarted) {
            qDebug() << "tap-n-hold event started";

            QWebView *webView = dynamic_cast<QWebView*>(object);
            FlickData *w = d->flickData.value(webView);
            qDebug() << w->pressPos; // get position 
        }
    }
}
```

My first attempt is simulating a right click event by using `sendEvent()`:

```
QMouseEvent pressEvent(QEvent::MouseButtonPress, w->pressPos,
  Qt::RightButton, Qt::RightButton, Qt::NoModifier);
QApplication::sendEvent(webView->page(), &pressEvent);
```

It seems like the event did send, but doesn't trigger the context menu, so I tried to implement `customContextMenu()` and emit `customContextMenuRequested()` signal directly:

```
emit QWidget::customContextMenuRequested(w->pressPos);
```

but failed with error:

```
error: cannot call member function ‘void QWidget::customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint&)’ without object
```

How can I trigger the context menu by QGestureEvent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a `QMouseEvent`, try sending a [`QContextMenuEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcontextmenuevent.html) directly.